# Mysql Select photo location after link

Tags: php, mysql

I have a **posts_photos** table where the **source** contains only the location of a photo example: photos/2021/04/demo_a827bcaf42d1b17f83cd35aa258d7b88.jpg

In table **posts_articles** **cover** also contains the location of a photo

In **posts_articles** I also have **text** where you can find a text mixed with the location of one or more photos
(&lt ;p&gt ;demo</p&gt ; &lt ;p>&lt ;img src=&quot ;
https://example.com/data/uploads/photos/2021/04/demo_a827bcaf42d1b17f83cd35aa258d7b88.jpg https://example.com/data/uploads/photos/2021/04/demo_da8180cdff56df2392b3842ae7d305e4.png )

```
global $db;
$query = $db->query("SELECT source FROM posts_photos UNION SELECT cover FROM posts_articles") or _error("SQL_ERROR_THROWEN");

$database_files = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $database_files[] = $row['source'];
} 

print_r($database_files);
```

it is possible to select from **posts_articles** table from the columns **text** just photo locations after https://example.com/data/uploads ?

Comment: Is after `one or more photos` a sample of DB data, or question content? If DB content is it really escaped in DB? Likely you could explode `https://example.com/data/uploads` from string in PHP or use regex on that

Comment: in some cases there is only one photo, but sometimes there can be more